# Redirecting php script adding log file size

Tags: php, bash, unix

I have the below php script which just assigns a variable.  When I run the script from unix command prompt  test.log file that is created has 1 byte.  It should be zero byte.  Not sure how the new line gets added.  How to prevent it so that test.log file has zero byte. 

**test.php**

```
<?php

$dir = "/usr/local/test";

?>
```

`/usr/bin/php  /usr/local/src/test.php  >> /usr/local/log/test.log 2>&1`

Comment: What happens when you just use `>` instead of `>>` i.e. `/usr/bin/php /usr/local/src/test.php > /usr/local/log/test.log 2>&1` ?

Comment: Add output of `hexdump -C /usr/local/log/test.log` to your question.

Comment: Check test.php for special characters: `cat -A test.php` or `cat -v test.php`

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Only new line exists in the file

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all and every new lines from the php file itselt, remember that php parser will only try to run what's embedded in the  end tag from the file, this way you're telling it that everything from the open tag to the end of the file is php code and should not be parsed as plain text.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Removed the every new line but it didn't work